# Reusing By Many Frame Classes java

Tags: java

Here is the code I came up with. I am a beginner java programmer who is very confused on what to do. I have to have a "Push me" button and a "Exit" Button created.

The main should also test out this panel. I will need to first instantiate a Frame and then instantiate your ExitPanel and add the ExitPanel to the Frame just before you show the Frame.

What am I doing wrong? Please explain and help thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;


    public class ExitPanel extends JPanel {


    public ExitPanel() {


            // set flow layout for the frame
            this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());



            JButton Exit = new JButton();

            Exit.setText("Exit");
            JButton Push = new JButton("Push Me");

            // add buttons to frame

            add(Exit);

            add(Push);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExitPanel exi = new ExitPanel();
    exi.pack();
    exi.setVisible(true);
    exi.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are instantaiting a  JPanel not a frame

**change this:**

```
ExitPanel extends JPanel
```

**to:**

```
ExitPanel extends JFrame
```